# Adding to superclass's struct in subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, mogenerator

I'm using Mogenerator to build classes for my CoreData, and I love the attribute names that it generates based off CoreData attributes like this in the header file of `_TAGUser`:

```
extern const struct TAGUserAttributes {
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *displayName;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *email;
} TAGUserAttributes;

@interface _TAGUser : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* displayName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* email;

@end
```

And this in the implementation file:

```
const struct TAGUserAttributes TAGUserAttributes = {
    .displayName = @"displayName",
    .email = @"email",
};

@implementation _TAGUser

@end
```

Now in the subclass `TAGUser`, I added this property to the header file:

```
@interface TAGUser : _TAGUser {}

@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSString *firstLetterOfDisplayName;

@end
```

And this to the implementation file:

```
@implementation TAGUser

- (NSString *)firstLetterOfDisplayName {
    return ((self.displayName != nil && self.displayName.length > 0) ?
        [self.displayName substringToIndex:1].uppercaseString :
        nil);
}

@end
```

Is there a way I can either extend or add to the struct `TAGUserAttributes` so that anywhere else in my code I can call on `TAGUserAttributes.firstLetterOfDisplayName` for KVO, section mapping in `NSFetchedResultsController`, etc?

Comment: you don't have to check: `self.displayName != nil `. In Objective-C messages sent to `nil` return 0, so `self.displayName.length` will be 0 if `self.displayName` is `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One does not simply extend a C struct. You have two possible approaches:

- Use `NSStringFromSelector(firstLetterOfDisplayName)` for KVO etc. This way you get some compiler safety. The compiler will complain if a selector with given name doesn't exist. However, the selector can exist anywhere in the visible scope, not only in your `TagUser` class, to make compiler happy.
- Another approach which I have seen here and there is to add another structure, containing a pointer to the original one. I can't figure out better naming now, but I hope it will be understandable:

in .h file:

```
extern const struct TAGUserAdditionalAttributes {
    const struct TAGUserAttributes* base;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString * firstLetterOfDisplayName;
} TAGUserAdditionalAttributes;
```

in .m file:

```
const struct TAGUserAdditionalAttributes TAGUserAdditionalAttributes = {
    .base = &TAGUserAttributes,
    .firstLetterOfDisplayName = @"firstLetterOfDisplayName"
};

   //then you can use "base" attributes like this:
   TAGUserAdditionalAttributes.base->displayName
```

Unfortunately the pointer syntax makes it quite ugly, but it still works.

Comment: Yeah I figured you can't just extend a C struct since it's not object oriented, but these make sense. Maybe I'll just do your second suggestion or make a property or method that is a wrapper for `NSStringFromSelector(firstLetterOfDisplayName)`. Gonna leave this open for a couple days to see if any other suggestions come through, but otherwise I'll accept the answer. Thanks!